# Hitting the tab key in the middle of the line inserts a tab instead of indenting

Tags: java, eclipse, settings

In Eclipse for Java, when I hit the tab key in the middle or at the end of a line, it inserts a tab instead of indenting. I can't find the setting to fix this, and an hour of googling has gotten me infinite pages about tabs vs. spaces and no answers. Please, help!

There is a setting I found under Java -> Editor -> Typing called "Tab key adjusts the indentation of the current line." It is definitely checked, but the indentation is only adjusted if the cursor is at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you can do:

- To indent several lines at once, you can select a portion of the text and press tab. This of course works for a single line too.
- Press command-I to auto-indent, pretty handy trick.

Neither of these options do exactly what you asked for (quickly indent this line one tab to the right), but that's all I can think of in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just switched to a new work computer, but I had Eclipse working like this on the old one. Unfortunately a decade of muscle memory makes retraining myself to use cmd-I a daunting prospect...